# onunload working for browser refresh but not for close

Tags: javascript

I have written some code, which will ask for confirmation before leaving the page. and if i say Yes to leave the page, then some cleanup needs to be done. Now the problem is `onunload` method is getting `executed for page refresh` but `not for page close`, why?

Code:

```
function checkBrowser(){

    window.onbeforeunload=warning;
    window.onunload = unloadPage;

}
function unloadPage() {
        if($('#loginOrNot').val() == 'loggedIn'){
            setTheExpertStatusToOffline();
            cleanUpChat();
        }
}
function warning(){
        if($('#loginOrNot').val() == 'loggedIn'){
            return "You are leaving the page"; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onunload` event works only when page is being redirected or refreshed. only `onbeforeunload` works while closing..

**Edit:**
Reason in simple terms may be that once browser closes,it doesn't execute the code that was supposed to happen for `onunload` event

Comment: is there any work around to execute a method after clicking leave page in confirmation box?

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload=function(){

document.getElementById('refresh').onclick=function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    window.location.reload(); // replace with your code
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {        
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";        
}

}​
```